# how to echo to a newly spawned xterm

Tags: bash, xterm

I need to write a bash script, which spawn a new xterm window and echo something over there. I have tried `echo "hello" | xterm &`, which does not work... furthermore, is it possible to do any command on the new xterm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xterm -e "echo "HELLO"; bash"
```

will keep the window open

Answer (score 0):

`xterm -e echo "hello"`. In general, `xterm -e anyprogram`.

Comment: Also, note that `-e` needs to be the last argument to `xterm`, if you specify more of them. Anything after `-e` will be considered an agrument to `anyprogram`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work from xfce terminal. The window auto closes. See my solution...

Comment: Hm, I've never used xfce's terminal, but looking at an online version of it's [man page](http://man.cx/xfce4-terminal%281%29/ug), it does seem to support the `-e` option. What did you try?

Comment: It does indeed echo. And then it closes. The problem is with the way terminals launch terminals. :-)

Comment: Ok, I see your point, the windows closes when the program is done. Micha's answer provides a way around it. EDIT: Bah, there are synchronization issues posting things here... :)